# Two different regular expressions in one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to put this regexs into one regex, but dont now how:

```
/^([0-9]{2,4})\-([0-9]{6,7})$/
/^\*([0-9]{4})$/
```

so the string can get XX(XX)-XXXXXX(X) or *XXXX

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to merge two regular expressions `A` and `B`, do:

```
/(A|B)/
```

This may change the order of one set of capturing parentheses. Also note that parentheses may not be needed, e.g. `A|B` may work in your simple case.

In other languages which support regular expressions with named captures, you can use those.

Comment: Yes though you don't really need the parentheses there; it's also important to note that the "|" operator binds more loosely than most others, so parentheses are very often necessary for grouping the left and right sides of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can OR-them this:

```
XX(XX)-XXXXXX(X)|*XXXX
```

so that either will match...

the trouble you get is that when the second one matches you don't get \1 ($1) and \2 ($2) set...

Answer (score 0):

Use an | (or).

i.e.:

```
/^([0-9]{2,4})\-([0-9]{6,7})|(\*([0-9]{4})$/
```